# How to detect for screenreaders/MSAA without focusing the flash movie?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-2, accessibility, screen-readers, section508

I am trying to [detect for the presence of assistive technology using flash](https://web.archive.org/web/20100613002817/http://www.webaim.org/techniques/flash/techniques.php).  When a Flash movie holding the actionscript below on frame 1 is loaded (and screenreader chatting to IE or Firefox over MSAA is active -- JAWS or NVDA), `Accessibility.isActive()` does not return "true" until the movie is focused.  Well, actually not until some "event" happens. The movie will just sit there until I right-click it & show flash player's context menu... it seems only then `Accessibility.isActive()` returns true.  Right-clicking is the only way I could get the movie to "wake up".

How do I get the movie to react on it's own and detect MSAA?  I've tried sending focus to it with Javascript... can a fake a right-click in javascript or actionscript?  Or do you know the events a right click is firing in a flash movie -- possibly I can programatically make that event happen?

My Actionscript:

```
var x = 0;  
//check if Microsoft Active Accessibility (MSAA) is active.  
//Setting takes 1-2 seconds to detect -- hence the setTimeout loop.  
function check508(){  
    if ( Accessibility.isActive() ) {  
       //remove this later... just visual for testing  
       logo.glogo.logotext.nextFrame();  
       //tell the page's javascript this is a 508 user  
       getURL("javascript:setAccessible();")  
    } else if (x<100) {  
       trace ("There is currently no active accessibility aid. Attempt " + x);  
       x++;  
       setTimeout(check508,200);  
    }  
}  
/*  
//FYI: only checks if browser is MSAA compliant, not that A.T. is actually running. Sigh.  
//This returns true immediately though.  
if (System.capabilities.hasAccessibility) {  
    logo.glogo.logotext.nextFrame();  
    getURL("javascript:setAccessible();")  
};  
*/  
check508();  
stop();
```

My HTML:

```
<embed id="detector" width="220" height="100" quality="high" wmode="window" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="/images/detect.swf" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="">
```

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks for the code highlight.  I'm new here.  :)

Also I'm not set on using Flash, it was just the solution I found most online.  If you have successfully detected assistive technology (specifically, JAWS) elsewhere through sniffing browser headers or something please pipe in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420853/flash-accessibility-detect-screen-reader), I found a solution:

```
var fl = document.getElementById("detector"); 
    if (fl) { 
        fl.focus();
    }
```

It had to be in pure javascript, as written above, attached to your `window.load` event. Trying either jQuery selectors `$("#detector").focus()` or omitting the if statement and just using `document.getElementById("detector").focus()` **...both did not work**.

I then send focus back to the top of the page within my `setAccessible()` function in the HTML page's Javascript so AT users are not stuck focused to the flash movie on page load.